Why don't atoms constantly emit electromagnetic radiation?
Consider a hydrogen atom: with one proton (and one neutron) and one electron. We can state that, on average, it is electrically neutral. We model the electron by a quantum wavefunction, and therefore as a stationary probability density with diffuse charge surrounding the proton/neutron. This solves the issue of Bohr's orbital model of the electron being a particle orbiting the nucleus like a planetary orbit, since the electron (carrying charge) would be emitting EM radiation and "fall" into the nucleus.
Now introducing the concept that an atom is constantly vibrating due to thermal energy, except at absolute zero Kelvin.
Wouldn't even the electron cloud/probability density of diffuse charge still emit EM radiation, reverting us back to the old Bohr model problem? Since the whole atom, including the electron cloud, would be vibrating back and forth (in random motion/direction of course).
My only reasoning for this not to occur, would be that the atom is electrically neutral. But, then what about an ion? Or when the atom is in a lattice/solid and dipole moments occur?

What particularly are you asking about? Yes, thermal vibrations will happen and so the atom will also be emitting EM radiation, but that EM radiation will obviously be Planck's distribution, i.e. thermal spectrum. Since the atom will be in thermal equilibrium with the EM radiation that it is itself receiving, there doesn't seem to be a problem.

If you are exiting atoms high enough that electronic transitions can occur, then you will see spectral lines. We usually demonstrate this in school with salts of alkali metals which produce bright color emissions when heated in a flame. These are also used in fireworks.

If it emits radiation due to thermal vibration and it also absorbs enough radiation to maintain its temperature then there is no problem. If it does not absorb radiation but only emits it, it will end up in the ground state and not emit any more, because the charge density is then constant at each point, nothing is "vibrating back and forth". So which case are you still worried about?!

The most common isotope of hydrogen (symbol 1H) consists of one proton, one electron, and NO neutrons.

Bohr pointed out the problem of collapse due to loss of energy by radiation, which is present in any model that respects EM theory (he referred to the Rutherford model which was the best one back then), and proposed what we know as the "Bohr model", which rejects EM theory when the system is in stationary states, and thus has no such problem. So the problem you're referring to is not a problem of the Bohr model, but a problem of those models that assume EM theory is valid all the time.


Now introducing the concept that an atom is constantly vibrating due to thermal energy, except at absolute zero Kelvin.
Wouldn't even the electron cloud/probability density of diffuse charge still emit EM radiation, reverting us back to the old Bohr model problem?

The concept of temperature doesn’t really apply for a single atom. But for a bunch of atoms in thermal equilibrium, at any temperature above absolute zero, yes the atoms will continuously be emitting EM radiation. This does not lead to the old Bohr model problem because they will also continuously be absorbing EM radiation. The net energy is constant on average.

To expand on the answer offered by Dale...

Now introducing the concept that an atom is constantly vibrating due to thermal energy, except at absolute zero Kelvin.

This is perhaps the first misconception; A single atom alone is not "vibrating" -- Vibrations are a result of interatomic forces between multiple atoms. We usually think of these like a bunch of springs connecting atoms in a solid or molecule. (This isn't really 100% accurate because the potential energy surface is not the same as a harmonic oscillator, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.)
What atoms can do, however, is exist in an excited state. This doesn't happen until fairly high temperatures (think, gas discharge tube). To use the gas discharge tube example: We'll assume the gas is fairly low pressure, to interatomic effects don't matter much. We'll also assume the tube has only a noble gas for simplicity (no molecular vibrations). You asked:

Wouldn't even the electron cloud/probability density of diffuse charge still emit EM radiation, reverting us back to the old Bohr model problem? Since the whole atom, including the electron cloud, would be vibrating back and forth (in random motion/direction of course).

If we consider a single atom floating in space (reasonably accurate for the tube described above), we can calculate the solutions to the Schrodinger Equation for bound electrons -- I.e, ones that do not have enough energy to escape the atom. When they are bound, these solutions form discrete energy levels with a finite lower bound (which happens to be about -13.6 eV relative to vacuum for hydrogen) -- Hence, even if in classical physics would allow a reduction in energy by getting closer to the nucleus, quantum physics forbids it.
In other words, it would emit EM radiation, but it would be restricted to certain energy levels for transitions. That is a purely quantum phenomenon that can't really be thought about through the classical lens. Going back to the atoms in a gas discharge tube, collisions with atoms/electrons can put them in an excited state -- I.e, an electron can jump between quantum states. Hence, in that environment, there's a certain percentage of excited states at any given time. Some of these excited states may transition back to the ground state, emitting a photon. This is the origin of an atom's emission spectrum. Importantly, this wouldn't happen at room temperature since the occupation of the high energy state would be so low that we can just call it unoccupied.
Atomic vibrations and rotations, like those in the spring example, are also bound by quantum physics. Since they are lower in energy, they emit longer wavelengths. This is the origin of infrared and radio wave emissions from solids and molecules. I'd recommend reading this link in addition to the ones above.

An atom in an environment of zero Kelvin would not radiate. In all realistic cases, an atom receives (absorbs) photons and sends (emits) photons. The emission number and the frequencies of the photons increase with increasing ambient temperature, which has been established in thermodynamics by the laws of heat exchange.
Bohr and later the probability density in orbital regions have to do with the thermodynamic processes only insofar as photons with different energies bring the electrons to different distances from the nucleus and after this emit photons with characteristic frequencies during relaxation.


Wouldn't even the electron cloud/probability density of diffuse charge still emit EM radiation

If the atom is under influence of some radiation (which is almost always the case), then yes, it will produce EM radiation.

... reverting us back to the old Bohr model problem? Since the whole atom, including the electron cloud, would be vibrating back and forth (in random motion/direction of course).

No. The problem you're referring to is that when system consists of accelerating charged particles, and is alone, not acted upon by any external agent, it loses energy by radiation, and thus it collapses to state of lower and lower energy. But this happens, already in classical theory, only when there is no other agent acting on the atom, and thus no source of energy; the atom in vacuum is assumed to be the only thing existing.
If there is a background radiation acting on the atom (e.g. thermal radiation, or zero point radiation), this radiation can do work on the charged particles in the atom and supply the energy for atom's emission, and the atom does not have to collapse. The same idea works in quantum theory; the atom interacts with the background radiation, and it can have some emission, but this does not mean it has to collapse.
Proving that it does not collapse in relativistic quantum theory is a harder mathematical task, but there is no obvious necessity that it has to collapse.
